# Sidebar with filters on google map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a filter on my map markers that takes multiple values into consideration.  However, as the markers get filtered, the sidebar does not.  I'm not generating any errors, but the load time for about 2000 records is taking well over 200 seconds.

Here is the code for making the sidebar:

```
function makeSidebar() {
var html = "";
for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
  if (!markers[i].setMap()) {
    html += '<p>' + markers[i].title + '<\/p>';
  }
}
document.getElementById("gridlist").innerHTML = html;
}
```

This is how my marker information:

```
downloadUrl('isxml.php', function (data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var places = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

  for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
    var markerData = {
      id: places[i].getAttribute('ReportID'),
      property_type: places[i].getAttribute('proptypedbname'),
      general_market_area: places[i].getAttribute('genmarkdbname'),
      gross_land_area: parseFloat(places[i].getAttribute('grosslandSF')),
      sale_date_formatted: places[i].getAttribute('recorddate')

    };

    markerData.sale_date = new Date(markerData.sale_date_formatted).getTime() / 1000;

    var markerIcon = customIcons[markerData.property_type] || {};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(places[i].getAttribute('lat')),
          parseFloat(places[i].getAttribute('lng'))
      ),
      title: places[i].getAttribute('propertyname'),
      icon: markerIcon.icon,
      data: markerData
    });


    // Push the marker to our array of markers.
    markers.push(marker);

  }

});
```

And my filtering system:

```
var $filters = $('[data-filter-key]'),
  filterObj = {
    checkbox: {},
    range: {
      sale_date: {
        from: null,
        to: null
      },
      gross_land_area: {
        from: null,
        to: null
      }
    }
  };

 $filters.on('change', function () {
 var $this = $(this),
    filterKey = $this.data('filter-key'),
    filterValue = $this.data('filter-value');

 filterObj.checkbox[filterKey] = filterObj.checkbox[filterKey] || {};

 if ($this.is(':checked')) {
  delete filterObj.checkbox[filterKey][filterValue];
} else {
  filterObj.checkbox[filterKey][filterValue] = true;
}

filterMarkers();
});

var $saledateFrom = $('#saledate_from'),
  $saledateTo = $('#saledate_to');

 $saledateFrom.datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeYear: true
 }).on('input change', function () {
var date = new Date($(this).val()).getTime() / 1000;

$saledateTo.datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
filterObj.range.sale_date.from = date || null;

filterMarkers();
});

$saledateTo.datepicker({
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
changeYear: true
}).on('input change', function () {
var date = new Date($(this).val()).getTime() / 1000;

$saledateFrom.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', date);
filterObj.range.sale_date.to = date || null;

filterMarkers();
});


$('#gross_land_area_from').on('input', function () {
filterObj.range.gross_land_area.from = parseFloat($(this).val()) || null;
filterMarkers();
});

$('#gross_land_area_to').on('input', function () {
filterObj.range.gross_land_area.to = parseFloat($(this).val()) || null;
filterMarkers();
});

function filterMarkers() {
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  var marker = markers[i],
      filterMatch = false;

  // Check checkbox filters
  for (var key in filterObj.checkbox) {
    if (!filterMatch && filterObj.checkbox.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (marker.data[key] && filterObj.checkbox[key].hasOwnProperty(marker.data[key])) {
        filterMatch = true;
      }
    }
  }

  // Check range filters
  for (var key in filterObj.range) {
    if (!filterMatch && filterObj.range.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var range = filterObj.range[key];

      if (marker.data[key] !== undefined && range.from && range.to) {
        var val = marker.data[key];

        filterMatch = !val || !(val >= range.from && val <= range.to);
      }

    }
  }

  // Toggle marker visibility
    if (marker.map === null && marker.getVisible()) {
    marker.setMap(map);
    delete marker.filtered;
         } else if (filterMatch) {
    marker.setMap(null);
    marker.filtered = true;
      }

}
  makeSidebar();
}
```

I've scratched my head over this for a while and am just lost now.  A second, third, or forth set of eyes can really help my out.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue (preferably a functional stackoverflow code snippet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the speed issue and think I have the filtering down.  placement of code means everything, that and some tweaking of the code.